# How to get report for user accessed SharePoint in past 30 days without enabling auditing feature

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, auditing, user-tracking

I am using SharePoint 2013 on-Premise and there is no auditing feature enabled.
But i want to get all information regarding which users accessed share point content for past 30 days.

Is there any ways to get such kind of reports or information without enabling auditing feature.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Auditing feature, you can find a third party solution for it, like Google Analytics.

There is an article which lists all 3rd party analytics tool for your reference:
 [3rd party analytics for SharePoint 2013](https://sharepointdragons.com/2015/06/17/3rd-party-analytics-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get some help from below article:

[Find the most visited sites in SharePoint 2013](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-most-visited-sites-in-sharepoint-2013.html)